# Has Mystra created new "Chosen"?

Tags: forgotten-realms

Has Mystra, the Goddess of Magic in Toril ever created new "Chosen" after half of her original Chosen now seem to have died off in the continuity?

EDIT:

As far as i know her Chosen were Elminster, The Seven sisters, Khelben (?)
Has Mystra made new chosen after half of the sisters are no more and she has returned as the godes of magic.

Comment: You need an indicator of what "now" means. Mystra was making new Chosen all the time, but the latest book I listed in the last FR question was the latest book.

Comment: I need to read Spellstorm before I can answer this definitively, but there's a definite candidate in The Herald.